# Rearrange values in dataframe based on condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, **where when the sum of Q1 24 - Q4 24 is between the number 1 - 2.5, I would like to place the number 2 in that row under Q4 24.**

**Data**

```
ID  type    Q1 24   Q2 24   Q3 24   Q4 24
AA  hi      2.0     1.2     0.5     0.6
AA  hello   0.7     2.0     0.6     0.6
AA  bye     0.6     0.6     0.6     0.4
AA  ok      0.3     0.4     0.2     0.2
```

**Desired**

```
ID  type    Q1 24   Q2 24   Q3 24   Q4 24
AA  hi      2.0     1.2     0.5     0.6
AA  hello   0.7     2.0     0.6     0.6
AA  bye     0.0     0.0     0.0     2.0
AA  ok      0.0     0.0     0.0     2.0
```

**Doing**

```
df.loc[df.iloc[:,2:].sum(axis=1)>1<2.5, ['Q1 24','Q2 24','Q3 24','Q4 24']]= 2
```

A SO member helped with the above script, but how would I only target that row under Q4 24. I am thinking I can utilize iloc again for this. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you are after including zeroing the other columns:

```
df.loc[df.filter(regex=r'^Q\d').sum(axis=1).between(1, 2.5), ['Q1 24','Q2 24','Q3 24','Q4 24']] = 0, 0, 0, 2

   ID   type  Q1 24  Q2 24  Q3 24  Q4 24
0  AA     hi    2.0    1.2    0.5    0.6
1  AA  hello    0.7    2.0    0.6    0.6
2  AA    bye      0      0      0    2.0
3  AA     ok      0      0      0    2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

I would use:

```
df.loc[df.filter(regex=r'^Q\d').sum(axis=1).between(1, 2.5), 'Q4 24'] = 2
```

Output:

```
   ID   type  Q1 24  Q2 24  Q3 24  Q4 24
0  AA     hi    2.0    1.2    0.5    0.6
1  AA  hello    0.7    2.0    0.6    0.6
2  AA    bye    0.6    0.6    0.6    2.0
3  AA     ok    0.3    0.4    0.2    2.0
```

##### adding 2 to last column and setting all the others to 0

```
sel = df.filter(regex=r'^Q\d')

df.loc[sel.sum(axis=1).between(1, 2.5), sel.columns] = [0]*(sel.shape[1]-1)+[2]
```

Output:

```
   ID   type  Q1 24  Q2 24  Q3 24  Q4 24
0  AA     hi    2.0    1.2    0.5    0.6
1  AA  hello    0.7    2.0    0.6    0.6
2  AA    bye    0.0    0.0    0.0    2.0
3  AA     ok    0.0    0.0    0.0    2.0
```

Comment: The question is "*I would like to place the number 2 in that row under Q4 24.*", Do you also want to set the other columns to 0?

Comment: oh yes this is what I mean - other values set to 0 @mozway

Comment: OK wasn't clear. But it looks like someone adapted my answer now. I added a generic way.

Comment: ok sure thank you - yes I need to be more clear - thank you

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative:

```
import numpy as np
df['Q4 24']=np.where((df[df.columns[2:]].sum(axis=1)<=2.5) & (df[df.columns[2:]].sum(axis=1)>=1),2,df['Q4 24'])
print(df)
'''
   ID   type  Q1 24  Q2 24  Q3 24  Q4 24
0  AA     hi    2.0    1.2    0.5    0.6
1  AA  hello    0.7    2.0    0.6    0.6
2  AA    bye    0.6    0.6    0.6    2.0
3  AA     ok    0.3    0.4    0.2    2.0
'''
```